# how to take photo type in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm making an API for uploading images. I want to retrieve the file type of the image, for example, the image is `.png` or `.jpeg` and other types of images.

[image]

```php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
$date_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$uploadFolder = '/images/all/';
$file_name = uniqid().'.png';

if(!$request->hasFile('image')) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'data'  => null,
        'message' => 'upload_file_not_found',
    ], 401);
}
$file = $request->file('image');
if(!$file->isValid()) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'data'  => null,
        'message' => 'invalid_file_upload',
    ], 401); 
}
$path = public_path() . $uploadFolder;

$file->move($path, $file_name);

$employee = Employee::find($id);
$employee->photo_file_path = $uploadFolder.$file_name;
$employee->photo_file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
// $employee->photo_file_type =
$employee->modified = $date_now;
```

This is my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Try with This.

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the extension of file to determine which type of file it is.

```
$type = $request->file->extension();
```

This way you can find the extension of file. ex. .jpeg, .png, etc.